# Unit Testing Framework - An error occurred while parsing entityname

Tags: unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have created simple MS Unit Test Project. `Assert.Equal(true, true)`.
When I want to run a test I receive a error from Resharper and Visual Studio.

"Unit test Runner failed to run tests

System.Xml.XmlException: An Error occured while parsing EnityName. Line 1, position 17."

Do I missing something.

Edit:
I can't add screenshot and I can't select text to copy. Ok I will write it the best I can.

```
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res,String arg)
at System.Xml.XmlText.ParseEnityName()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImplparseEnityReference
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextLoader.ParsePartialContent(XmlNode parentNode,String innerxmltext, xmlNodeType nt)
at System.Xml.XmlElement.set_InnerXml(string value)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.InferSettingHelper.AppendOrModifyChild(XpathNavigator,String nodePatH,String nodeNAME,sTRING INNERxML)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.InferSettingsHelper.UpdatedRunConfiguration(XPathNavigator, ArchitectureeffectivePlatform,FrameworkVersion effectiveFramework,String resultsDirectory,String solutionDirectory,String binariesRootDirectory)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.InferSettingsHelper.MergeRunSettingsAndFindCompatibleSource()
at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestProvider.MSTest11.MsTest11Runner.Run(IRemoteTaskServer server,String assemblyLocation,String runConfigurationFilename,IUnitTestRun run)
```

Comment: Yeah but what this have to do with vs-unit-testing-framework

Comment: I don't have app.config in my Unit Test Project. I have added one but It didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you able to run unit tests with Test Explorer that comes with Visual Studio? (may be we can isolate if this is something to do with resharper unittest provider)

Comment: When I run unit test with Test Explorer whole Visual Studio crashes. Something inside Visual Studio is broken. I guess If you have that problem the only solution is to reinstall whole Visual Studio.

Comment: You're right :( Repair might help. Just curious, which version of VS is this? Did you install any updates?

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2013 2 Update.I forgot to mention but already existing unit test projects works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this problem you don't need to reinstall Visual Studio or Resharper.

The problem was in a file path to my projects. This would explains why other Unit Test projects were fine because there were in a different location.

I guess this a bug inside Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework. If you have unit test project inside folders with special charts like '&' then Visual Studio will crash or Resharper will return this message.

I wonder where I can report this bug.

Answer (score 3):

I have just run into this problem too and followed the advice above. 
First my path had a folder named ...\m&e...
Then I copied the whole project folder to a new location without an '&' in the path.
After that everything was working well.